# Assignment of same generic types with wildcard arguments

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, type-parameter

Why the following  method does not give a compiler error?  :

```
    public void func3(List<? extends Number> l1, List<? extends Number> l2) {
        l1 = l2;
    }
```

Run-time error could occur in the method, but why the compiler thinks the static-type of `l2` is the same as `l1`? ( hence, there's no compiler error )

Comment: But... they're exactly the same parameterized type. Why do you think a compiler error should occur here? Note you can't _add_ to a `List<? extends Anything>`.

Comment: Why their types are the same? since wildcards are used, their types could be anything that inherits from `Number`. It seems to me that the compiler decides this implicitly. If it were written `public <T extends Number> void func3(List<T> l1, List<T> l2)` then I'd agree about `lst1`  and `lst2` having the same types since we explicitly define it to be `T`.

Comment: I think you're confusing the static type of the parameters, and the "run-time type" of the arguments (though of course generics don't exist at run-time). The whole point of wildcards is to say, "The real type can be anything, so long as it's assignable to the upper bound(s)". So, both `l1` and `l2` are saying what matters is that the elements are assignable to `Number`, and what the actual type of the parameters is _does not matter_. Whenever you read an element _from either list_, all you know is that it's a `Number`.

Comment: Thanks , didn't know this. Do you have any idea though what the parameterized type of `l1` and `l2` are in the above method?. Because of the wildcard it seems that we can't know, but all we can know is that the type will be assignable to `Number`.

Comment: The parameterized type _is_ `List<? extends Number>`. The generic type argument is `? extends Number`. That's a type, and it says, "Something that is assignable to `Number`". The point of generics is to allow this sort of ambiguity regarding the "real" type, while maintaining a strong static type system.

Comment: Since I deleted one of my comments, here's the link to the Q&A I had: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). It won't necessarily answer your question, but understanding the concept of PECS may help. Both of your lists are "producers of `Number`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but why the compiler thinks the static-type of l2 is the same as l1? (
> hence, there's no compiler error )

Because they are exactly the same. The compile-time type of the variables `l1` and `l2` are both `List<? extends Number>`.

> Run-time error could occur in the method

No, runtime error cannot occur. The assignment is completely safe. Anything that can be pointed to by the type of `l2` can be pointed to by the type of `l1`.

> since wildcards are used, their types could be anything that inherits
> from Number.

I think you are thinking of the fact that, for example, you can pass a `List<Integer>` as first argument and a `List<Double>` as second argument. Yes, and that's perfectly fine. Then `l1` will point to the `List<Integer>` and `l2` will point to the `List<Double>`. Then when you do `l1 = l2;`, you make both `l1` and `l2` point to the `List<Double>`. And that's fine. Since `l1` has type `List<? extends Number>`, it can sometimes point to a `List<Integer>` and at other times point to a `List<Double>`. Consider a simpler example:

```
public void func4(Object o1, Object o2) {
    o1 = o2;
}
```

I can pass a `String` as first argument and an `Integer` as second argument, and that's perfectly fine. The assignment `o1 = o2;` will cause both `o1` and `o2` to point to the `Integer` object, and `o1` and `o2` can do that since they have type `Object`.